# How do I get Django form errors from Ajax to appear on the user screen?

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

Perhaps I'm not thinking clearly...but it would seem to make sense to me that if I am submitting a form via AJAX...the same form that I can submit via the traditional HTML method that I should be able to get the form errors and display them just as I would via a HTML submit?  I can certainly get the form.errors in my console if I print them.....but I can't seem to figure out how to get them back to the template so that they render on the user's screen.  JSONRESPONSE shows them in a different screen...but how can I just get them back on the form itself?

Here is my View...

```
class CreateProcedureView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = NewProcedure
    form_class = CreateProcedureForm
    template_name = 'create_procedure.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    return JsonResponse({'success': True })

def form_invalid(self, form):
    response = JsonResponse({"error": "there was an error"})
    response.status_code = 403 # To announce that the user isn't allowed to publish
    return response

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Procedures:procedure_main_menu'))
    else:
        self.object = None
        user = request.user
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        file_form = NewProcedureFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file[]')
        if form.is_valid() and file_form.is_valid():
            procedure_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            procedure_instance.user = user
            procedure_instance.save()
            list=[]
            for f in files:
                procedure_file_instance = NewProcedureFiles(attachments=f, new_procedure=procedure_instance)
                procedure_file_instance.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            file_form = NewProcedureFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Here is my Ajax...

```
     $.ajax({
         url: "{% url 'Procedures:create_procedure' %}",
         headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
         method: "post",
         data: $("#forms").serialize() + "&status=" + "Submitted",
         success: function(data){
               alert(data.message);
           },
           error: function(data){
              alert(data.status); 
              alert(data.responseJSON.error); 
           }
     });
    });
```

Comment: This has a decent walk through of the issues involved: https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Answer (score 1):

for example if you have a span tag under the form input

```
<span id="error_first_name"></span>
```

use Jquery to append
$('#error_first_name").text(data.responseJSON.error.first_name[0])